# MySQL not return result when key id is not found

Tags: mysql, key, inner-join

I have lines of mySQL code to show a set of result linked with two tables. Related by a key id. The problem occurs when there's no key matches another table - no result show. So my idea is I want to have some condition in mySQL like if(id='999','General','concat(something with no inner join)). Please have a look on my code:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT if( log_db.log_bid = '999', 'General', 
CONCAT( 'B', bk_rtype, '-', LPAD( bk_id, 5, '0' ) ) ) AS booking_no,
 booking_db.bk_flg1 AS flight
FROM log_db
INNER JOIN booking_db ON booking_db.bk_id = log_db.log_bid
WHERE log_db.log_stts = '1'
ORDER BY log_db.log_id DESC
```

According to my code. I expect if log_bid='999' a booking_no should returns 'General' but it doesn't. Please suggest.

Comment: By definition, `INNER JOIN ... ON` requires a match in both tables. I don't follow what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you might want to use a regular join so you still get a result if one table has no matching record, and then possibly use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to deal with the `null` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a LEFT OUTER JOIN like this.

```sql
SELECT log_db.log_bid,
   CASE WHEN booking_db.bk_id IS NULL THEN 'General' 
   ELSE CONCAT( 'B', bk_rtype, '-', LPAD( bk_id, 5, '0' ) ) END AS booking_no,
   booking_db.bk_flg1 AS flight
FROM log_db
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking_db ON booking_db.bk_id = log_db.log_bid
WHERE log_db.log_stts = '1'
ORDER BY log_db.log_id DESC
```

This will give you all the records from the first table that match your where criteria joined up with the records from the second table (or null records if no match is found).